# How to avoid repeating the adjective "corresponding"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I have the following sentence:

> If the context relies on a single anchor (Self, Parent, Following), the nodes within the **corresponding** scope are treated with regard to this context and a **corresponding** node is created in the output XML file.

In general, many times I need the word "corresponding" and don't know much synonyms or equivalent structures for the sentence.

I looked it up in [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/corresponding?s=t) but none of the synonyms are as strong as the "corresponding" and can be used in its place.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about writing style. Perhaps [Writers.SE](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit?

Comment: Take out the second 'corresponding' with no replacement added in. The sentence will clean up well.

Comment: @plafort then it doesn't imply that the node is created according to the attributes of the "context". for example they have the same name

Comment: It would take a big leap of logic for the reader to take any other meaning from it.

Comment: @Flimzy I would check the website, but I am a learner. I changed it to a general question about the equivalents of "corresponding". If there are any, one can tell me here.

Comment: @Ahmad: In this particular case, I suspect your use of English is sufficiently good that Flimzy's recommendation is better.

Comment: Did you check any synonyms in a dictionary? Anyway I agree you can't leave out the second "corresponding" because then you lose the relationship it indicates. How about "related? The basic question in your title should be answered using a dictionary, or if done pls. share your findings and concern.

Comment: @user3169 I checked some, none are as strong as "corresponding". In fact, I found no suitable word. "related" may be used for the first one. thanks, By the way, I asked the question in Writer.SE as you suggested.

Comment: @user3169 I came up with "matching" which seems suitable, I answer the question myself.

Comment: @user3169 by a suggestion from the other site "respective" is best word for my purpose. By the way, they counted my question off-topic there too.

Comment: If you need a list of synonyms, use a dictionary or thesaurus. I don't think your edit has made this any more on-topic.

Comment: I don't have an account there so I can't see the off-topic reason. A question about repeated word use might be OK but asking about grammar probably not.

Comment: @Flimzy you are right, but I searched the dictionary and found no suitable word, I edited my question to say what I have tried with a link to a famous dictionary.

Comment: "For each" seems like it would fit here, as would "matching", as you suggested.  "and *for each* a node is..."

Answer (score 2):

I found few words as strong as "corresponding", the best word I found is "respective". the words are

- associated
- related
- respective
- matching

However, in my case, "related" or "matching"  works:

> If the context relies on a single anchor (Self, Parent, Following), the nodes within the **related** scope are treated with regard to this context and a **corresponding** node is created in the output XML file.